# TSQL: How does transaction works with insertion to table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Let say I have the following statement

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(colums)
VALUES (values)
```

What if, for whatever reason, one of the operation fails. Is everything will be stopped and all the insertion that succeeded will be rolled back?

If something go wrong, I want only the insertion that failed to be leftover. But all the rest before and after to go forward.

Thanks for helping

Comment: That is a single statement.  There are no other inserts.  Nothing is before or after it.  Do you mean if you have it in a loop?  Wrapped in a transaction?  Need more code.

Comment: basher is right, this is a one row insert. It will fail or work. There's no in-between here. Please review your question and someone might help you.

Comment: @basher: I didn't mean that but you question kind of answered part of my question. Then I guess I'll need to wrap the insert statement with a loop and a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes will rollback everything if is in same block.

But if you are using a stored procedure and inside you have `EXEC myStoredProcedure` you need to count the levels of Transact if you want to have own logic when internal SP have

```
BeginTransaction/commit

@@TRANCOUNT (Transact-SQL)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx

YOU CAN USE

```
TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Valentin

www.bluelabs.ca

Answer (score 0):

If that's your only statement, then it is being executed in the context of an **implicit** transaction. If that operation fails, then the transaction (so in this case - this one single `INSERT` statement) will be **rolled back** and the database looks as if this statement never happened.

If you need to have this behavior for a series of 10 `INSERT` statements, then you must use an **explicit** transaction (use the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` command to start it, `COMMIT` to commit the changes when everything was successful, or `ROLLBACK` when something went wrong, to "undo" all the changes since the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`).

If you want multiple `INSERT` operations all "protected" by a transaction, you can use something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO myTable(column1) VALUES (1)
    INSERT INTO myTable(column1) VALUES (2)
    INSERT INTO myTable(column1) VALUES (3)
    ...
    INSERT INTO myTable(column1) VALUES (42)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Can u please provide a sample?

Comment: Thank for the sample. Maybe I need to save in a temporary table then loop through the the temp table.